# What does $^{(L)}K$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $K$ and $L$ be two sets. What does $^{(L)}K$ mean? Is it $\underbrace{K\times K\times\dots}_{\text{card L times}}$? I came across this notation somewhere and couldn't quite figure it out.

Thank you

Comment: Where did you come across this notation?

Comment: @nik- In the book "Elements of Set Theory" by Enderton. Pg. 139.

Comment: It is just ${}^L K$, the set of functions from $L$ to $K$. Enderton is considering the two sets ${}^{L_1}K$ and ${}^{L_2}K$, and the notation may appear ambiguous, so he uses parentheses to clarify: Without parentheses, one could look at ${}^{L_1}K$, and think that it means the set of functions $f: L\to{}^1 K$, as opposed to the set of functions $f:L_1\to K$.